# C++ - ReadProcessMemory to buffer, WriteProcessMemory (with new value on same buffer) reverts buffer to old value

Tags: c++, winapi, buffer, readprocessmemory

I don't know why this happens and I'm most curious.
I've managed to write/read successfully NOT using a buffer on WriteProcessMemory, but I'd like to know why this happens.

This is how it works. You throw test

target.cpp (Process that outputs address of variable to read/write)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int test = 5;
string pero = "hola";
cout << sizeof(test);
cout<<"Address of test is :" <<&test <<endl; //Address to put on Principal.cpp
cin.get(); //Wait that other process writes then I manually continue.
cout << "Value of test is: " << test<<endl; //Outputs 5, should output 20.
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Principal.cpp (reads and writes on address). Start on main.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream> // For STL i/o
#include <ctime>    // For std::chrono
#include <thread>   // For std::this_thread
using namespace std;
DWORD FindProcessId(const char *name)
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;
    PROCESSENTRY32 ProcEntry;
    ProcEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &ProcEntry))
    {
        {
            if (stricmp(ProcEntry.szExeFile, name) == 0)
                return ProcEntry.th32ProcessID;
            while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &ProcEntry))
                if (stricmp(ProcEntry.szExeFile, name) == 0)
                {
                    return ProcEntry.th32ProcessID;
                }
        }
    }
}
 // IMPORTANT PART STARTS HERE.
int main()
{
    int buffer;
    DWORD Address = 0x28ff28; //Address of int test.
    DWORD ProcessId = FindProcessId("test.exe");

    if (ProcessId == 0)
        cout << "Doesn't exist.";
    else
        cout << "Process Id is : " << ProcessId << endl;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, ProcessId);
    if (hProcess == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Error in HANDLE";
    }
    if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)Address, (LPVOID)&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == 0)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error is " << error << endl;
    }

    cout << "Buffer is: " << buffer << endl; //Outputs 5

    buffer = 20; // Want to write 20 and then read variable on test.exe.
    if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)Address, (LPCVOID)&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == 0)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error is " << error << endl;
    }
    cout << "Buffer is: " << buffer << endl; //Outputs 5, should output 20.
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

What happens here.

- ReadMemory To buffer
- buffer = 5
- Make buffer = 20
- Write buffer to Memory.
- buffer = 5; <- ¿Why?

I'd appreciate a lot if someone could explain this to me!

Comment: The return value of `FindProcessId` is indeterminate if the target process is not found. You need a `return 0` statement if the search loop exits without finding a match. It is also leaking the handle returned by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`. And `main` isn't doing very good error handling.

Comment: "*buffer = 5; <- ¿Why?*" - are you claiming that `buffer` inside of `principal.cpp` has reverted back to 5 after calling `WriteProcessMemory`? Or that `test` inside of `target.cpp` is never updated to 20?

Comment: Your compiler issued a warning. Don't ignore it.

Comment: Hello @RemyLebeau, buffer inside principal.cpp reverts back to 5.

Comment: @HeTheMan that is simply not possible given the code you have shown

Comment: @RemyLebeu Well, that's what the output showed. That's why im surprised.

Answer (score -1):

A few things.

```
 DWORD Address = 0x28ff28;
```

how are you getting this, are you just entering from what the program above told you what the address was?

If you are getting the address from the above address, you need to find the **entry point** of the program and add **0x28ff28** to that number.

**EDIT:** If you use a memory viewer, you can see that the address the program spits out does not point that int, and the offset I said does not as well. You need to find out where it is stored relative to the program starting path. I was wrong in my assumption that you could use the number that was spit out by the program above.

The way window is designed is it will randomly start the program at a different address for security reasons, and the address you are seeing is an offset from where ever the program starts at.

You should be able to find the base address from **nModule.modBaseAddr**, but you might need to cast it to a *uint64_t* if you are running the program in 64-bit.

I hope this helps.

edit:
also you can do this instead of iterating over the snapshot

```
hWnd_ = FindWindow(nullptr, processName.c_str());
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd_, &pid_);
```

also make sure you are running as admin.

Comment: `&test` will always return the **absolute** address of `test`. You don't need to add any offsets. ASLR has no effect. Besides, `FindWindow` does not take the name of a process. It takes a window name and window class name.